# Empty string with Tesseract

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to read different cropped images from a big file and I manage to read most of them but there are some of them which return an empty string when I try to read them with tesseract.

[image: String to read with tesseract]

The code is just this line:

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(cv2.imread("img.png"), lang="eng")
```

Is there anything I can try to be able to read these kind of images?

Thanks in advance

Edit:
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thresholding the image before passing it to `pytesseract` increases the accuracy.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Grayscale image
img = Image.open('num.png').convert('L')
ret,img = cv2.threshold(np.array(img), 125, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Older versions of pytesseract need a pillow image
# Convert back if needed
img = Image.fromarray(img.astype(np.uint8))

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))
```

This printed out

```
5.78 / C02
```

**Edit:**
Doing just thresholding on the second image returns `11.1`.  Another step that can help is to set the [page segmentation mode](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality#page-segmentation-method) to "Treat the image as a single text line." with the config `--psm 7`.  Doing this on the second image returns `11.1 "202 '`, with the quotation marks coming from the partial text at the top.  To ignore those, you can also set what characters to search for with a whitelist by the config `-c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789.%`.  Everything together:

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config='--psm 7 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789.%')
```

This returns `11.1  202`.  Clearly pytesseract is having a hard time with that percent symbol, which I'm not sure how to improve on that with image processing or config changes.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I had tried some pre-processing like thresholds and it might work for some but not for others like the one I've included in the message. Is there any combination of pre-processing that could work? Many thanks again!

Comment: @AKruger which version did you used ? 3 or 4 ?

Comment: Thanks a lot!! the configuration --psm 7 really helped a lot, even with the % thing I'm hitting almost 100%, thank you!!