# Tesseract yielding low quality text recognition from image

Tags: numpy, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

We have an image from which we want to read all the text contained in it. I am trying the following code, getting extremely unsatisfactory results. Any idea what is wrong and how can I make it generic enough to accurately read all text contained in a vast number of images when the text quality is fairly decent (like this one)?

```
import pytesseract
import cv2
import numpy as np
import urllib
import requests
from PIL import Image

def url_to_image(url):
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
    image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    return image

url = 'https://www.fantasticfunandlearning.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/FB-nonfiction-dinosaurs.jpg'
img = url_to_image(url)

retval, img = cv2.threshold(img,200,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
img = cv2.resize(img,(0,0),fx=3,fy=3)
img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(11,11),0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,9)
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print('recognition:', txt)
```

There is a fair amount of text in the top part as well as in the bottom part, both go totally unnoticed, and only the middle part is OCRed and that too partially.

I got the idea of this code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54261928) answer.

For context, when I upload the image in Google Lens, this is what I get:

[image]